# Convert IEnumerable<XElement> to XElement

Tags: ienumerable, xelement

The return type of my query is `IEnumerable<XElement>`. how can i convert the resultant data to `XElement` type? is it possible? could some body help me to understand this.

```
var resQ = from e in docElmnt.Descendants(xmlns + Constants.T_ROOT)
                             .Where(x => x.Attribute(Constants.T_ID).Value == "testid") 
           select e;
```

I have to pass resQ as a parameter to the below function. in order to do that I have to convert resQ to XElement type.

```
Database.usp_InsertTestNQuestions(tid, qId, qstn, ans, resQ );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as your query only returns a single result, you can either call Single() or First() on the result (also, there's no need for the extra query syntax up top):

```
// Use if there should be only one value.
// Will throw an Exception if there are no results or more than one.
var resQ = docElmnt.Descendents(xmlns + Constants.T_ROOT)
                   .Single(x => x.Attribute(Constants.T_ID).Value == "testid");

// Use if there could be more than one result and you want the first.
// Will throw an Exception if there are no results.
var resQ = docElmnt.Descendents(xmlns + Contants.T_ROOT)
                   .First(x => x.Attribute(Constants.T_ID).Value == "testid");
```

If you want to handle the case when no results are returned for the query without throwing an Exception, you can use `SingleOrDefault` (which will still throw an Exception if you get more than one result) or `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Note that `First()` can be called without generating exceptions if the collection returns *more* than one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each element in the query and then call the method with your enumerator.

```
resQ.ToList().ForEach(e => ...func... );
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Justin's answer, you may want to allow for 0 elements returned or some other condition.

In that case, simply do a:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> resQ = docElmnt.Descendents(xmlns + Constants.T_ROOT)
                   .Where(x => x.Attribute(Constants.T_ID).Value == "testid");
if(resQ.Count() == 0) {
  //handle no elements returned
} else if(resQ.Count() > 1) {
  //handle more than 1 elements returned
} else {
  XElement single = resQ.Single();
}
```

Most of the time I find it's best not to throw an error-- unless having exactly 1 returned is really important.

Comment: I read somewhere that .Any() is better to use then .Count() ... may have been on Eric Lippert's blog.